# How to navigate to other screen in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created a simple code practise flutter web.

I have been trying to navigate between two screen in flutter web. But one i click the button in first screen and navigate to second screen, the second screen is show blank with debug flag at the top right. Once i refresh the second screen data is coming.

How to resolve this issue?

Here is the code

```
import 'package:temp/providers/Increment_provider.dart';
import 'package:temp/screens/Detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<IncrementProvider>(
      create: (btx) => IncrementProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
         
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
       
          DetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => DetailScreen(),},
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<IncrementProvider>(context, listen: false);
   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
    
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
       
        child: Column(
         
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Consumer<IncrementProvider>(builder: (ctx,counter,ch)=>Text(
                '${counter.count}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
                        
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context,DetailScreen.routeName);
              },
              tooltip: 'Press the button',
              child: Icon(Icons.view_agenda),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => counter.incrementor(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:temp/providers/Increment_provider.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName='/Detail_screen';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter=Provider.of<IncrementProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
     
      body: Center(child:Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('The incremented value is ${counter.count}'),
         
        ],
       
      ),),
       
    );
    
  }
  
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IncrementProvider with ChangeNotifier{
 int _count=0;

int get count=> _count;

void incrementor (){
  _count+=1;

  notifyListeners();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Navigator for:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(DetailScreen.routeName);
```

and your **DetailScreen** don't need the column as the **Center** Widget is doing your logic.

Also, with this kind of "weird" behavior, is always good to post here your `flutter doctor -v` so we can tell if you're using a different version of **Flutter**, if plugins are up to date, etc.

Also, I'll recommend to fist delete your provider from your **DetailScreen** to see if that affects the behavior. I tried your code without your Provider class and works using iOS emulator. Plus, to double check, force **TextStyle** color over your text just to be double sure a **dark/light theme** from your device is not affecting that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the provider from the code and used argument to pass the data between the screens.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:temp/screens/Detail_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(

          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {

          DetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => DetailScreen(),},
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    int count=0;

void increment(){
  setState(() {
    count+=1;
    print(count);
  });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
    Text(
                '$count',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),


            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(DetailScreen.routeName,arguments: count);
              },
              tooltip: 'Press the button',
              child: Icon(Icons.view_agenda),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName='/Detail_screen';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final count=ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as int;
    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(child:Text('The incremented value is $count',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),

    );

  }

}
```

P.S: I am testing this code in Chrome Browser where this issue is observed. I have not tested in any emulators.

Please run the code in the chrome browser.